# my code doesnotwork without refreshing the page. we crate

Tags: javascript, database, oracle, oracle-apex

We created an Oracle APEX application by using JavaScript and **CSS** about the meeting room. When the room is full, the page must be red. However, it shows green if I don't refresh the page. How can I fix it? I want it to work properly without refreshing.

I checked my JavaScript code, however I couldn't catch up the code.

```javascript
function color() {
  if (apex.item("P2_D_DUZENLEYEN").node.innerHTML != undefined) {
    document.body.style.background = "url(#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#red.jpg)";
  }
  else {
    document.body.style.background = "url(#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#green-2.jpg)";
  }
}
color();
displayTime();
setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
displayDay();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I couldn't catch up the code?"  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Hello! You are setting an interval for displayTime, but you aren't showing us what that function does. You are only calling the color() function once. Do you mean to call it multiple times at an interval? What does displayTime do? To help you better, we need to see more of your code.

Comment: You are checking the value of the page item (P2_D_DUZENLEYEN) to determine the color of the background. Generally speaking, the values of page items in the DOM don't until you refresh the page. When you refresh the page, the latest values from the database are checked and used to render the new page. There are, of course, various ways to solve this issue. Generally, one would use a little JavaScript with Ajax to get the latest value from the database.

Comment: could it be that you forgot to set the JS property: Execution Options->Fire on Initialization->Yes